# Set Json Attribute on existing class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have an existing class in an external assembly which I can't change.
I would like to serialize an object from this class with Newtonsoft JSON.Net, but not all the properties.

Normally I can do this with the JsonIgnoreAttribute attribute like this:

```cs
public class TestJsonClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

But since I can't change the class, is there a way to ignore a property without attributes?

Comment: You might want to do it at runtime, but it a bit expensive as you'll have to use reflection. Take a look at this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/4fb1b301-618d-4b5e-8b89-e0595c005b16/

Comment: I was hoping for a non reflection way (if possible)

Comment: Why don't you deserialize to `TestJsonClass` and then copy the values to original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inherit class and override property with appropriate annotations or copy property values in a completely new class.